# Smarty foreach / shuffle/random and limit

Tags: random, foreach, smarty, limit, shuffle

I want to get items **foreach**, shuffle them and limit the output to 4 items.

i've this. (displays all items)

```
{content block_id=27}
{if $_content_27|count >0}
{foreach name=aussen item=box_data from=$_content_27}
  <article class="news_row_article col-lg-3">
          <div><img src="images/ImgResponsive_Placeholder.png" alt=""/></div>
          <h3 class="news_row_headline">{$box_data.content_heading}</h3>
          <p class="news_row_content">{$box_data.content_body}</p>
</article>
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

i've found this

```
{foreach array_rand($a_firm_display,5) as $i} 
<a href="{$smarty.const.HOST}{$a_firm_display[$i].url_rewriting}"><img src="{$a_firm_display[$i].firm_logo}" /></a> 
{/foreach}
```

or this
[Generate distinct smarty random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830240/generate-distinct-smarty-random-numbers)

```
    {assign var="distinct_numbers" value=array_fill(1,15,'x')}
{assign var="distinct_numbers" value=array_keys($distinct_numbers)}
{assign var="x" value=shuffle($distinct_numbers)}

{* result *}

{foreach from=$distinct_numbers item="value"}
    {$value} |
{/foreach}
```

hm..somehow get the items from $_content_27 put them into array, output, and limit them ?

any ideas ?

Comment: That logic doesn't really belong in a template. You should place it in the PHP and just let Smarty handle the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use shuffle and for instead of foreach, if you don't mind losing the array keys:

```
{$_content_27=$_content_27|@shuffle}
{for $iter=0 to 3}
    ...
    {$_content_27.$iter.content_heading}
    ...
{/for}
```

Answer (score 3):

For older version of smarty I found very useful this snippet to shuffle my key => value array

```
{capture}{$items|@shuffle}{/capture}
```

Just place it before your foreach loop, I hope it helps somebody.